# SPRESNSEのSDCHIライブラリを用いてフォルダを作成したい。

Tags: c++, c, spresense, arduino

SPRESNSEで記録したデータをSD内に保存するプログラムをSDHCIライブラリを用いて作成したのですが、今までのデータが全て同じ場所に保存されてしまうのでは、データの整理が面倒に感じています。

そこで、SPRESENSEの電源ONになったときに新規フォルダを作成してデータをそこに保存していくようにしたいなと考えているのですが、SDHCIライブラリではフォルダを作成するような関数が見当たりません...

どのようにして作成したらよいでしょうか。どなたかご助言頂けますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ドキュメントを見る限り、ディレクトリを作成する `SD.mkdir()` や 任意のファイル名を指定してオープンする `SD.open()` など、基本的なファイル/ディレクトリの操作を行う関数は用意されているように見えます。

https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-arduino-ide/developer-guide#sdhci_library

**追記:**

上記で紹介したページからいくつかのサンプルにリンクされており、この中で
SD カード上のファイルを読み書きするサンプル [read_write.ino](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-arduino-compatible/tree/master/Arduino15/packages/SPRESENSE/hardware/spresense/1.0.0/libraries/SDHCI/examples/read_write/read_write.ino) が参考になると思います。

> ```c
> SD.mkdir("dir/");
> myFile = SD.open("dir/test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
> ```

作成したディレクトリ名を含めて、開きたいファイルのパス名を指定すればOKなはず。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！しっかりと用意されていたんですね。失念しておりました。
追加で質問させていただきたいのですが、ディレクトリを作成できても、ファイルの保存先を作成したフォルダに指定できなくて困っています。
何か良い方法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: サンプルを使った例を追記しました。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございました。おかげ様で解決いたしました。